# JButton (Java Swing) selected backgorund color disable change

Tags: java, swing, click, jbutton

I would like to disable color change on JButton to GRAY upon clicking on it.

I  tried with:

1. UIManager.put("Button.select",null);

but as I found out Button.select is not avalible for Windows L&F.

2. I tried to create child of JButton and put this in paint method:

...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      if (this.isSelected()) {
             int w = getWidth();
             int h = getHeight();
             g.setColor(backgroundColor); 
             g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
             g.setColor(Color.white); 
            g.drawString(...);
         }   
    }
```

but isSelected is never true

3. I tried to add listener and change background upon click ,but there is still shown gray background upon click.

What should I do to disable this gray background upon click?

This is how it is on click now:

[image]

This is how I want it:

[image]

Comment: I think what you're after is `isArmed` from the buttons `ButtonModel`.  Since you appear to have customised the button in someways, mind posting a runnable example

Comment: M need to provide your own look and feel delegate